# Magento 2: How to override the model?

Tags: overrides, model, magento2.2, php-7

How to override the model:

```
vendor/magento/module-Customer/Model/Address/AbstractAddress.php
```

For removing the validation of the last name. What can I do?

I have already overriden this file using the **around plugin** method, but it is still throwing an error.

Comment: Hope it helps - https://magenticians.com/override-model-magento-2/

Comment: but it shows some error

Comment: please post the whole code with Error

Comment: i want to remove last name validation in checkout page.wt can i do

Comment: You can't override abstract class, you should using virtualType for this case.

Comment: i can't understand your answer

Answer (score 2):

Create **di.xml** File

Path : `app/code/{vendorName}/{ModuleName}/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddres" type="{vendorName}\{ModuleName}\Model\Address\AbstractAddres" />
</config>
```

**Create Model file**

Path : `app/code/{vendorName}/{ModuleName}/Model/Address/`**AbstractAddres.php**

```
namespace {vendorName}\{ModuleName}\Model\Address;

    class AbstractAddres extends \Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddres
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            echo "Model Rewrite Working"; die();

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

remove below code for last name validation.

```
if (!\Zend_Validate::is($this->getLastname(), 'NotEmpty')) {
    $errors[] = __('Please enter the last name.');
}
```

Comment: yes.Removed it.But it throws error like......@Please check shipping information@

Comment: that is something different error. Not related with Last Name

Comment: how to overcome this...........

Comment: check your recent modification related with shipping

Comment: or some time  the page was loading.................

Answer (score 0):

Hello you need to o override that model using plugin.

One more thing you need to change into database

Find last name attribute into eav_attibute and find column is_require.

Change value 1 to 0 for that attribute.

Flush the catch and try it....

Thanks

Comment: already changed it.but it shows  error

Comment: If you do change into core file then it's work?

Comment: yes.it's work in core

Comment: Can you please put your code into issue of around plugin.make sure it is non protected method.

Comment: i'm sure. no non-public method

Comment: Non public or public method?

Comment: please update override php file

Comment: Non-pubilc method not given

Comment: Please add your plugin code into your post

Comment: my file was like this...vendor/magento/module-Customer/Model/Address/AbstractAddress.php

Comment: can u update modified AbstractAddress.php file?

Comment: Try to do using preference and override that file

Comment: Ok..It will working correctly?

Comment: Yes It will work..

Comment: Have you Checked?

Comment: not working preference

Answer (score 0):

> Stackoverflow\Customer\Plugin\Model\Address\AbstractAddress

```
/**
 * Validate address attribute values
 *
 * @return bool|array
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
 */
public function aroundValidate(\Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddress $subject, \Closure $proceed)
{
    $result = $proceed();

    if (!\Zend_Validate::is($this->getLastname(), 'NotEmpty')) {
        return true;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Companyname/Modulename/Model/Address/AbstractAddress.php copy core class into above location and make entry in di.xml

Answer (score -1):

You create your CUSTOM\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddress.php class extending Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddress

And In your di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddress" type="CUSTOM\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddress"/>
```

Or You can create plugin with a function aroundValidate() in class CUSTOM\Customer\Plugin\AbstractAddressPlugin.php

And in yout di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddress">
    <plugin name="cutom_customer_address_plugin"
            type="CUSTOM\Customer\Plugin\AbstractAddressPlugin" />
</type>
```

Comment: Hi, it didn't work i tried both ways didn't work